# How to create "pages" for search results in HTML, PHP, Javascript, MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Let's assume for following structure:

A table with two columns: `id, name.`

Let's assume the table consists of thousands of rows.

I have a search engine that allows me to search by free text.

The query I use to retrieve the data is as following:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$search%'
```

Let us also assume that the entire results are saved as `associative` array in a variable name `$results`.

I want to display them in a CSS designed html table (This is important because it slows the browser data loading).

Now, I have 2 options here:

Load all the thousands of results into the same page at once, and use the "display" to change between "pages".

Or,

I could with ajax for example, make a different search for each number I click that changes a the `"LIMIT TAB_NUMBER*NUM_OF_RESULTS_PER_PAGE, NUM_OF_RESULTS_PER_PAGE"`.

Anyone got better idea?

Comment: this is just only the backend process, have you tried anything in the front end? I would recommend doing it in ajax and having a datatable to populate the result

Comment: Don't ever load thousands of search results at once - why would you do that? The user isn't going to be scrolling through thousands - it's all wasted time and effort.

Comment: You can get for example 100 records at the beginning and make 10 pages out of it. You can add a link "more" and if that is clicked, return another set of 100 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use offset and limit in query and use pagination. you should not pull all the records because if you pull all records all data will come to page but will not display but you will display 20 or 30 records. so every time you get all records on page which is bad practise. you can use ajax also. that is good

Comment: What do you mean by "pagination"?

Comment: this is example of pagination and some tutorial. 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928